# Unable to install python-recsys module

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install python-recsys module. But i get this error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-recsys
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for python-recsys

I am using Python 3.4
The code that i am using to install the module is:
`pip.exe install python-recsys`

Answer (score 2):

Recsys is not supported by python 3.X but only python 2.7.